# Laravel GPG - Issue when attemping to Encode

Tags: php, laravel, gnupg

So, I'm attempting to do some encoding using GPG in Laravel. I've found the package https://github.com/jasonhinkle/php-gpg which, while no longer maintained, looks like it should still work for what I need to do. I've installed the code in a custom folder `app/Classes/GPG`, and included it in the `artisan` Command that will use it:

```
class CustomCommand extends Command {
  private $gpg = null;
  private $publicKey = null;

  protected $signature = "custom:command";

  public function __construct() {
    $this->publicKey = new \GPG_Public_Key(file_get_contents(base_path()."/path/to/public/key.asc"));
    $this->gpg = new \GPG();

    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function handle() {
    $this->gpg->encrypt($this->publicKey, "Hello World!");
  }
}
```

With the above code, all is well; `$this->gpg` and `$this->publicKey` are both initialized without issue, but as soon as I try to run `php artisan custom:command`, I get the following error:

> (1/1) **ErrorException**
>   String offset cast occurred
>   in **GPG.php** line 112

Like 112 of `GPG.php` is as follows:

```
private function gpg_session($key_id, $key_type, $session_key, $public_key){
  ...
  $s = base64_decode($public_key);
  $l = floor((ord($s[0]) * 256 + ord($s[1]) + 7) / 8);
  if($key_type) {
    ...
    $l2 = floor((ord($s[$l + 2]) * 256 + ord($s[$l + 3]) + 7) / 8) + 2; // 112
  }
}
```

Doing a `dd($s, $l)` results in a jumbled mess of a `string` which I likely can't post here, and `256.0`.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies with this line:

```
$l = floor((ord($s[0]) * 256 + ord($s[1]) + 7) / 8); // 256.0
```

As `$l` is a `float`, and not an `integer`, this line:

```
$l2 = floor((ord($s[$l + 2]) * 256 + ord($s[$l + 3]) + 7) / 8) + 2; // String offset cast occurred
```

fails in both cases of trying to access `$s[$l ...]`. To fix this issue, simply wrap the declaration of `$l` in an `intval()` call to explictly set it as an `integer`:

```
$l = intval(floor((ord($s[0]) * 256 + ord($s[1]) + 7) / 8)); // 256
```

The reason for this error is due to versions of PHP. Prior to PHP 5.4, trying to access an array with a `float` was valid, due to conversion. Given `$l = 256.0`, `$s[$l]` would try to access `$s[256]`. In PHP 5.4+, this error was introduced, and, due to this package not being maintained, was never handled properly. Hopefully this helps someone else out.